# How can I keep the keyboard layout between reboots?

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout

I have a stripped down Debian Bullseye server (commandline only).

I plugged in my localized keyboard and obviously it handled incorrectly. No worries, I did:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

And selected the correct configuration.

However to make it acting I also have to call

```
sudo setupcon
```

Across reboots this is not surviving, every single time I have to call

```
sudo setupcon
```

I know I can add 'setupcon' to run after login (although it's tricky as it needs sudo).

But I'm curious, how is this supposed to be made permanent?

My `etc/default/keyboard` contains the correct setting I chosed.

I'm so sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any elegant answers to this particular question.

Note: I also tried installing console data:

```
sudo apt install console-data
```

But installing it didn't solve my problem.

```
sudo systemctl status keyboard-setup-service: loaded and active (exited)
```

Comment: Check if `~/.keyboard` exists, see `man 1 setupcon` (When it exists, remove it)

Comment: I had to do `rm /etc/console-setup/cached_*` then it is all sorted out.